# How to change innerHTML element that goes after event.target

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I do XHR, by clicking on p ajax query, the result should be output to the element that is next in DOM, I have a lot of identical elements, so I use event.target. How do I add responsiveText to the next event.target div?

JS code:

```
  function loadMoreInfo(e){
var target = e.target;
var serialNumber= target.dataset.serialnumber;
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
var method = "GET";
var url="ajx_php.php/?serial_number=";
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById('div-more-info-id').innerHTML = ajax.responseText; //change only one div
    }
}
ajax.open(method, url+serialNumber, true);
ajax.send();}
```

HTML code:

```
<p class='p-more-info' id='p-more-info-id' data-serialnumber='$serial_number'>more info     &#9660</p> 
<div class='div-more-info' id='div-more-info-id'> </div>
```

Comment: Is the div in the p or outside of it?

Comment: @epascarello her go next, otside,look html code in the top

Comment: Well there is no closing </p> so hard to tell from the code above.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling

Comment: @epascarello `p closing : <p(that e.target)></p><div>there must be responsiveText</div>` , problem in this code `document.getElementById('div-more-info-id').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;`

Comment: well you can't have more than one element with the same id, so the link I posted would solve your issues

Comment: @epascarello i do not have same id, but your link solve my problem, thanks for the help.That working `target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) solve my issues, thank @epascarello

Answer (score 0):

You could get the id attribute of the `<p>` tag, parse out the identifier with a regex and use it to select the `<div>`

```
function loadMoreInfo(e){
    var target = e.target;
    var serialNumber= target.dataset.serialnumber;
    var identifier = target.id.replace(/^p-more-info-(.+)$/, '$1');

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var method = "GET";
    var url="ajx_php.php/?serial_number=";
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('div-more-info-' + identifier).innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajax.open(method, url+serialNumber, true);
    ajax.send();
}
```